# Appcenter codepush mistakenly assembled an Apk lost update

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push, appcenter

I used to update my react native app OTA using codepush and Someday mistakenly I generated apk after I already distributed my apk, since this moment any one with the old Apk can't have the latest updates as Codepush only push updates to the new APK, so is the any way to get back to this old apk as I don't need the new one and all of my users have the old apk